# 'showsPageRange' is deprecated

Tags: ios, uiprintinteractioncntrler

I have this warning "'showsPageRange' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Pages can be removed from the print preview, so page range is always shown." that I would like to remove. This is my code

```
printController.showsPageRange = YES;
```

Since default value for showsPageRange is false, and in my code it's set to true, I don't know if I can safely just remove this line.

I just don't understand this message "Pages can be removed from the print preview, so page range is always shown." It says that page range is always shown, ok, but what does the option to remove pages from the print preview has to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

Because page range is always shown, there is no need for this property showsPageRange anymore. It is safe to remove this line from your code.